# Is it possible to use Facebook quick replies and galleries in Twilio Flex?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, messenger, twilio-programmable-chat

I can't seem to find out how to use rich media elements such as quick replies, buttons and carousels within Twilio Flex. Currently I'm not using Twilio Autopilot as I'm using a Dialogflow's NLP.  Is this possible?